# How to write program which monitors text file for new data

Tags: c, file-io, io-redirection

I have a program, code below, which monitors a text file and takes the data line by line and prints output to another file.

When the program is run, not all the data will be present in the file.  The text file will be written to over several days.

I need to be able to simulate the program writing to the text input file.  How would I do this?

I am running on Windows 7 and to test this I ran this cmd line:

TYPE CON>input.txt

But then when I run my code in is null and so the code immediately returns.  How can I fix this so code correctly opens file.  I also need it to continue 'polling' (not sure if that is correct term) until it sees an 'e' character as first character of line and only then can close.

I run program with arguments: myprog.exe input.txt output.txt

Here is the code:

```
/* Prints ranges of numbers in format n number1 number2 where character n
   indicates 2 numbers to follow. print from n1+1 to n2.  e indicates end 
   of numbers to process.
*/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   char s[100];
   int mn, mx;
   int items = 0;

   if(argc == 3) {
      FILE* in=fopen(argv[1],"r+");
      FILE* out=fopen(argv[2],"w");
      if(in && out) {
         setbuf(in, NULL);
         setbuf(out, NULL);
         while((items = (fscanf(in, "%s %d %d", &s, &mn, &mx))) > 0) {
            switch(s[0]) {
            case 'n':
               /* print nos. to out */
               while(mn++ < mx) {
                  fprintf(out, "%d\n", mn);
                  fflush(out);
               }

               break;
            case 'e':  fclose(in); fclose(out); return 0;
            default:
               /* error */
               break;
            }
         }
         fclose(in);
         fclose(out);
      }

   } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Wrong no arguments\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was remove the + in opening the input file:

```
FILE* in=fopen(argv[1],"r");
```

I am guessing that if I redirect stdin to the input file, then stdin is only one way - so would not allow input file to be writeable.